# How can I animate individual characters in a TextView?

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to take the text displayed in a TextView and apply tweening to individual characters.  I can't think of how to accomplish this without having a separate view for each character.  I hope that's not the only way to solve this problem, because it just seems incredibly messy.

Comment: If you want a cleaner approach, you could subclass TextView and encapsulate the functionality you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

create your own custom view, and use that. you can animate them in every way you like, using canvas you have given in onDraw() method.

this may help:
http://www.apleben.com/2011/01/custom-android-view-the-definition/